# Filter out posts based on a certain post_meta on the WordPress REST API

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm going to explain this the best way possible, and see if someone might be able to help me out.

**Website 1** (*Posts located here*):

Let's say that our WordPress REST API endpoint is: https://example-1.com/wp-json/v2/posts

Since the native `v2/posts` endpoint doesn't support `post_meta`, I added support using the following:

```
add_filter('rest_post_query', function($args, $request) {
    $args += [
        'meta_key' => $request['meta_key'],
        'meta_value' => $request['meta_value'],
        'meta_query' => $request['meta_query'],
    ];

    return $args;
}, 99, 2);
```

Now, I am able to successfully query the REST API using the following endpoint: https://example-1.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1&meta_key=original_id

I successfully get all posts that have a `original_id` as the `post_meta` over the WordPress REST API.

---

**Website 2** (*Pulling in posts from website #1*):

Now, on this website I want to pull in **ALL** posts **EXCEPT** posts that have the `post_meta` of `original_id`.

So I have the following code:

```
$response = wp_remote_get(
    https://example-1.com/wp-json/v2/posts?page=' . $page_number . '&meta_key=original_id'
);
```

This pulls in **ONLY** the posts with the `original_id` `post_meta`.

**Question**:
How would I be able to do the opposite of that `wp_remote_get` call? Pull in all posts except posts that have `original_id` as the `post_meta`.

Since I added `meta_query` support to the REST API, how would I be able to utilize that?

Comment: Add `meta_compare`? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question is a duplication of [this question here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/407760/filter-out-posts-based-on-a-certain-post-meta-on-the-wordpress-rest-api/407762?noredirect=1#comment595536_407762).